# Hibernate many to one partial composite foreign key

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I have situation where i have to map partial composite key as foreign key for example, hibernate is it possible to map partial composite key as foreign key?

```
class Employee {
    @embededId
    EmployeeId id;
}

class Mobile {
    @Id
    int mobId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="empId" referencecolumnname="empId")
    Employee emp;
}

class EmployeeId {
    private int empId;
    private int deptId;
}
```